# How to compare all file names from a given directory java?

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I want to compare all file names from a given directory

**Input/Output code:**

```java
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static String Directory = sc.next(); 
static File folder = new File(Directory);
static File[]listofFiles = folder.listFiles();
static String[] underFiles = folder.list();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.walk(Directory);
}

public void walk( String path ) {
    File root = new File( path );
    File[] list = root.listFiles();
    if (list == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (File f : list) {
        if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
            walk( f.getAbsolutePath() );
            System.out.println( "Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
        }
        else {
            System.out.println( "File:" + f.getName() );
        }
    }
}
```

The **input** is to give a directory path. The **output** will show all of the files in the given directory. How can I compare equal file names in this directory?

Comment: What do you mean by "equal file names" ? There are no equal file names in the same directory.

Comment: Yes there are equal file names, if they are in two subdirectories, but in the same main directory.

Comment: You could use a map. For each filename, you can store a list of paths where this filename exists. So this would like something like the following: `{"abc.txt": ["first/path/to/file", "second/different/filepath"], "def.txt": [...] }`

Comment: [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)

Comment: As Brimbo said, use a `Map<String, List<Path>>` along with `computeIfAbsent(filename, f -> new LinkedList<Path>()).add(f.getPath())` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String path = "/your/file-path/here";

    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(path))) {
        Map<String, List<Path>> map = 
                 paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                      .collect(groupingBy(p -> p.getFileName().toString()));

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

`Files.walk` will walk all the hierarchy of files for you. The only thing you need to do is to consume the `Path`s from `Stream`.

---

If you still want to stick with your own code. Then you might do this instead:

```java
public static void walk(String path, Map<String, List<String>> map) {

    File root = new File(path);
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    if (list == null) return;

    for (File f : list) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            walk(f.getAbsolutePath(), map);
            System.out.println("Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());
        } else {
            map.computeIfAbsent(f.getName(), k -> new ArrayList())
                    .add(f.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("File:" + f.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "/your/file-path/here";

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    walk(fileName, map);

    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for a very clear answer. I'm having just one problem. A error is appearing when I'm calling the method: walk in the Main method. Where is the mistake there?

Comment: @Massin_NYC I've just double checked. Both code snippets work on my laptop. Make sure you're using a valid fileName. This works on my MacOS : `String fileName = "/users/<put-your-user-name-here>/Documents";`

Comment: did you put the second code snippet in another method?

Comment: @Massin_NYC Yes, it's inside `main` method. Check the updated code snippets.

Comment: Thanks, there are no more errors. But it's showing all the file names and their paths. It than looks like this 
Input: 
C:\Users\Massin\Desktop\DupliFinder\GleicherName_Test. 
Output: 
File:Test2.txt
Dir:C:\Users\Massin\Desktop\DupliFinder\GleicherName_Test\Misn
File:Test.txt
Dir:C:\Users\Massin\Desktop\DupliFinder\GleicherName_Test\xc

{Test2.txt=[C:\Users\Massin\Desktop\DupliFinder\GleicherName_Test\Misn\Test2.txt], C:\Users\Massin\Desktop\DupliFinder\GleicherName_Test\xc\Test.txt]} 

So it's not showing the files with the same name (you can see it in the last two output lines).

Comment: @Massin_NYC Make sure your file structure is correct. This is my test output: `{photo.png=[/users/eto/Documents/nested/photo.png, /users/eto/Documents/photo.png]}`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to locate directories that contain files with the same file name. For example, on a Windows machine, you may have several folders that contain image files. Usually each one of those folders will have a file named *Thumbs.db*. So you would like to know the names of the folders that contain a file named *Thumbs.db*.

The following code calls method [walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) of class `java.nio.file.Files` and manipulates the [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) returned by that method to create a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where the `Map` key is the file name and the `Map` value is a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of all the folders that contain a file with that name.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class WalkTree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get(args[0]);
        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(path)) {
            Map<Path, List<Path>> map = paths.filter(p -> Files.isRegularFile(p))
                                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getFileName(),
                                                                       p -> new ArrayList<Path>(List.of(p.getParent())),
                                                                       (l1, l2) -> {l1.addAll(l2); return l1;}));
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The first parameter to the `toMap` method, in the above code, is a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) that returns the `Map` key. The second parameter is another `Function` that returns the `Map` value. And the third parameter is a [BinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) that merges two different `Map` values that both have the same `Map` key.